# css, select previous anchor

Tags: css, anchor, html-lists

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="selected">Text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

how do I select the anchor for **Text 2** without adding an extra class? (and no javascript)

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.list li a.selected ******{background-color:#000}
</style>
```

output:

```
<li><a href="" style="background-color:#000;">Text 2</a></li>
```

Comment: why no javascript?  That would be the easiest way to do it and also the 'standard'.

Comment: I just wanted it to work even when JS is disabled. But thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a previous sibling selector, which unfortunately doesn't exist. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector) for useful links on what is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Without javascript your results will not always work across each browser. Check this link by [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

This is the way it would be done using CSS3, This pesudo-class is currently not supported in Internet Explorer.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.list li:nth-child(2) a { background:#000 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

the nth child selector can do this. browser support varies.

try:

`ul.list li:nth-child(2) a { background:#000; }`

Ref: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to simply select *th child element. (Except firstChild element, which let you specify the first child element.) But alternatively you can consistently assign numbered ID's to li element, for example

```
<li id="1"><a href="">Text 1</a></li>
<li id="2"><a href="">Text 2</a></li>
<li id="3"><a href="">Text 3</a></li>
```

Then you can use that to specify *th li element using the value in id attribute. So your css should be

```
ul.list li[id="2"] a { background-color: #000; }
```